# Are there any more mathematical journals or websites with the "problems and solutions"?

Tags: reference-request, problem-solving, journals

Are there any more mathematical journals or websites with the "problems and solutions"? such as , the *American Mathematical Monthly* and *Crux Mathematicorum*

Answer (score 8):

Problems columns I found (in 2009) useful to challenge undergraduates.  Some of them may no longer be current.  But even those may be interesting to consult past issues in your school library!

Mathematics Magazine   https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/mathematics-magazine

Mathematical Mayhem   https://www.facebook.com/pg/Mathematical-Mayhem-1253467234689081/

College Math J    https://www.maa.org/press/periodicals/college-mathematics-journal/the-college-mathematics-journal

Nieuw Archief  http://www.nieuwarchief.nl/homeitems.php?onderwerp=6

Math Spectrum   http://www.appliedprobability.org/content.aspx?Group=ms&Page=ms

Answer (score 2):

- [The College Mathematics
  Journal](https://www.tandfonline.com/doi/abs/10.1080/07468342.2017.1403145?journalCode=ucmj20)
- [Pi Mu Epsilon](http://pme-math.org/pme-journal-problem-department)
- [MathProblems Journal](http://www.mathproblems-ks.org/)